# Set HTML tag on XPage via Themes element

Tags: xpages

I want to disable Google translate from HTML in Chrome on my XPage:

```
<html translate="no">
```

If I set

```
<xp:this.attrs>      
    <xp:attr name="translate" value="no"></xp:attr>     
</xp:this.attrs>
```

it will work but then I have to do this on every xpage.

If I set this via a custom control that resides on each xpage then I get:

```
<div translate="no">
```

which is not useful.

I am trying to set it via a Themes design element that is loaded for the whole application:

```
<control>
       <name>ViewRoot</name>
          <property>
             <name>attrs</name>
                <complex type="xp_attr">
                   <property>
                      <name>name</name>
                      <value>translate</value>
                   </property>
                   <property>
                      <name>value</name>
                      <value>no</value>
                </property>
             </complex>
          </property>
    </control>
```

or

```
<control>
        <name>ViewRoot</name>
        <property>
            <name>translate</name>
            <value>no</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

but both options does not work. The Theme is loaded.

What am I doing wrong I wonder?

Comment: The docu https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/user/wpd_theme_naming_control_ent.html says that ViewRoot matches the body - that's not what you want. Try `Html`

Comment: Hello! I must be doing something wrong because I set <control  override="true">
  <name>Html</name>
  <property>
   <name>translate</name>
   <value>no</value>
  </property>  
 </control> but nothing noticeable in the source has changed

Comment: Open a ticket with HCL then